# Rails+Postgres - hstore automatic conversion of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore, postgresql-9.3

I'm using `hstore` on one of my models to store a hash with float values.  I need to periodically access and perform calculations the values in the store.

My current solution for working with these values is to convert them to float everywhere I access them, which is very un-DRY.  Is there a way for me to modify the store_accessor method to automatically covert any values that I read from the store to floats?

I know I can do this to specific keys by writing a function for them [as described in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) but I have a very long list of possible keys, so this way is also not very DRY.

Comment: May be this be useful
https://github.com/jalkoby/active_store_accessor

Comment: Thanks Vakiliy - your gem works great - its just a bit more than I need for this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent used `hstore` before, but studied the documentation you provided in the question. Well, `hstore` looks really useful (too bad it is available only in postgreSQL DB, but definitely learned something new).

From reading the documentation,

> NOTE - If you are using PostgreSQL specific columns like hstore or
>   json there is no need for the serialization provided by store. Simply
>   use store_accessor instead to generate the accessor methods. Be aware
>   that these columns use a string keyed hash and do not allow access
>   using a symbol.

Also:

> The stored attribute names can be retrieved using stored_attributes.
>
> `User.stored_attributes[:settings] # [:color, :homepage]`

So, we will be getting the seperate fields in a `stored_attribute` using `stored_attributes` hash and will be getting the fields we declared on the `stored_attribute` as an array. Now, we need to override the accessors for all the elements in the array. We can use [define_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method) to dynamically override the accessors. This is what I came up with.

```
class WorkingBill < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :prices, :cost_price, :selling_price

  stored_attributes[:prices].each do |price_column_name|
    define_method("#{key}=") do |value|
      super(value.to_f)
    end

    define_method(key) do
      super.to_f
    end
  end
end
```

I havent tested this code as I dont have a development environment right now. Also, I have a doubt whether `super` call will work inside `define_method`. So, just try it out. I will also test it once I get a development environment.

Also, as @Vakily commented, the gem https://github.com/jalkoby/active_store_accessor seems to do this better and also handles boolean, integer fields also.